# Migrating from Nativescript 5 -Nativescript 6 - IPA file size is too large in release build

Tags: ios, build, nativescript, ipa, tns

Migrating from NS5 -NS6
- This command generates ipa with size ~40 mb 
tns build ios --bundle --provision [development_profile] --for-device --copy-to ~/Desktop/lastest_debug.ipa
- This command generates ipa with size ~100 mb
tns build ios --bundle --release --provision [distribution_profile] --for-device --copy-to ~/Desktop/lastest_release.ipa

Why this discrepancy? This happening after migrated project from NS5 - NS6?
Any thing needs to be done for IOS specifically in NS 6?
Project environment: 
nativescript - 6.2.0
tns-core-modules - 6.3.2
tns-android - 6.2.0
tns-ios - 6.2.0
Xcode version 10.3.0
current CocoaPods version is newer than 1.0.0

Any body has faced this issues while migrating project from NS 5 to NS6?

Comment: we are using @nota/nativescript-webview-ext  (6.2.1) plugin and I suspect it has dependency on swift lang support!!! Any body has any clue how to disable and or use which version to disable this?

Comment: The plugin needs the extension to work as intended. Did you try checking content of IPA, that might give some idea where exactly it's growing.

Comment: IPA has swift folder having libraries for swift support, which was not there before migrating to NS6. Any thing do with xcode setting or something?

Comment: Did you also compare the file size of binary, assets and JS files?

Comment: What do you put for `--distribution-profile`???????

Answer (score 0):

Try setting "always embed swift standard libraries" to "No" in xcode build config.
may be your new built ipa size is getting bigger because of embed swift support settings with IPA. You can ignore that setting.

steps :

open Xcode, In build Settings of your project.xcodeproj file, set "always embed swift standard libraries" to "No".
Now build and check size.